# Windows 10 boot error

Tags: windows-10, bios, multi-boot, uefi, fat32

I recently created a bootable USB it using Rufus on a Windows 10 laptop in order to install Windows 10 add alongside Ubuntu for a dual boot on my desktop. I created the USB in Fat32 format. My empty partition on my desktop was  also Fat32. When I entered my BIOS and booted into the USB, however, I was immediately presented with the following screen:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  Status: 0xc000000f

  Info: A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed.
```

I have no idea what this means. However, Rufus was behaving strangely when I created my drive. After it was finished, it presented me with the option to start creating the bootable drive again, and when I realized it was doing this and quit Rufus, it warned me that the drive may not be complete. How can I fix this?

Comment: Get a portable version of Rufus and try it again. If this doesn't work then re download the Windows 10 ISO and write it again using Rufus (portable). The error is usually to do with corrupted files or fine system. Also try format NFTS in through Rufus.